# Summarizing multiple columns by two variables

Tags: r

This is my first time ever using R so please forgive me if this question is not worded properly. I have a .csv file that I imported into R and I am trying to summarize some data. each row of data if for a given year, study site, and area and each column has the number of species present. There are 4 columns for each species as there were 4 surveys where the species could have been seen.

I am trying to get the sum of each species by year and study site. Columns 5:8 are one species, 9:12 another, 13:16 another and so on. Here is the code that I thought would summarize columns 5:8 by year (YYYY) and study area (SAR):

```
aggregate(test[,5:8],by = list("SAR","YYYY"), FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

This gives me the error message that "argument must have the same length". Can anyone help me through this initial step?

Here is some of the data:

```
SAR    YYYY GRID_ID WID     col1 col2 col3 col4
BCPALP  2005    1   1189    NA  NA  0   0
BCPALP  2005    1   1190    0   NA  0   0
BCPALP  2005    1   1191    0   0   NA  NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1192    0   NA  NA  NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1194    NA  NA  1   NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1195    NA  NA  1   NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1196    0   NA  0   NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1198    0   NA  0   NA
BCPALP  2005    1   1199    0   NA  0   0
```

I'm hoping to get an output that is something like this:

```
SAR    YYYY    total of columns 1:4
BCPALP 2005    2
```

This is the code I just tried.

```
aggregate(cbind("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")~SAR+YYYY, test, FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
```

It gives me an error message that states "variable lengths differ (found for 'SAR')".

I went back and checked the data and all the variable lengths are the same.

Comment: Please show some example data and expected output.

Comment: Here is some of the data that I have:

Comment: Please update it in your post

Comment: BTW, Can you specify `YYYY` and `SAR`s position in the dataset

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble figuring out how to add a portion of my data table to the comment. The SAR and YYYY are the headings for columns 1 and 2 respectively.

Comment: @HVS My pleasure. It is difficult to get used to SO in the initial stage.

Comment: @akrun I still get the error message "variable lengths differ (found for 'SAR')"

Comment: @HVS Based on the example you showed, I am not getting any error.

Comment: If you notice my code, I didn't quote the `"col1"`, `"col2"` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use either `aggregate` or `data.table` or `dplyr`.  If we use the formula method for `aggregate`, we need to set the `na.action=NULL` when there are `NA` values in different columns.  By default, the `na.action=na.omit`, so if there is a single NA in one of the columns, that row will be removed from the calculation.

```
aggregate(cbind(col1, col2, col3, col4)~SAR+YYYY, test,
                        FUN=sum, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
#   SAR YYYY col1 col2 col3 col4
#1 BCPALP 2005    0    0    2    0
```

---

Using `dplyr`, we group by 'SAR', 'YYYY', and use `summarise_each` to get the `sum` of each of the 'col'.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>%
     group_by(SAR, YYYY) %>%
     summarise_each(funs(sum=sum(., na.rm=TRUE)), 5:ncol(test))
#     SAR  YYYY  col1  col2  col3  col4
#   (chr) (int) (int) (int) (int) (int)
#1 BCPALP  2005     0     0     2     0
```

---

Or with `data.table`.  We convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(test)`), grouped by 'SAR', 'YYYY', we loop though the Subset of Data.table (`.SD`) and get the `sum`.  The columns to be looped are specified in the `.SDcols`.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE), by = .(SAR, YYYY),
             .SDcols= 5:ncol(test)]  
#      SAR YYYY col1 col2 col3 col4
#1: BCPALP 2005    0    0    2    0
```

#### Update

Suppose after aggregating we need to get the row wise sum for columns 'col1:col4', then 'col5:col8' etc.

```
 DT <- setDT(test1)[, lapply(.SD, sum, na.rm=TRUE),
              by = .(SAR, YYYY), .SDcols= 5:ncol(test1)]
 DT1 <- melt(DT, id.var=c('SAR', 'YYYY'))[, i1 := as.numeric(gl(.N, 4, .N)),
            .(SAR, YYYY)]
 dcast(DT1, SAR+YYYY~i1, value.var='value', sum)
```

#### data

```
 test <- structure(list(SAR = c("BCPALP", "BCPALP",
"BCPALP", "BCPALP", 
"BCPALP", "BCPALP", "BCPALP", "BCPALP", "BCPALP"), YYYY = c(2005L, 
2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L, 2005L),
GRID_ID = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), WID = c(1189L, 1190L, 1191L, 
1192L, 1194L, 1195L, 1196L, 1198L, 1199L), col1 = c(NA, 0L, 0L, 
0L, NA, NA, 0L, 0L, 0L), col2 = c(NA, NA, 0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA), col3 = c(0L, 0L, NA, NA, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L), col4 = c(0L, 
0L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 0L)), .Names = c("SAR", "YYYY",
"GRID_ID", 
"WID", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"), class = "data.frame", 
 row.names = c(NA, -9L))

set.seed(24)
m1 <- matrix(sample(c(NA,0:5), 9*4, replace=TRUE),ncol=4, 
           dimnames=list(NULL, paste0('col', 5:8)))
test1 <- cbind(test, m1)
```

Comment: Also, how can I tell R to summarize columns 5:8, 9:12,13:16 and so on until the end of my data?

Comment: @HVS As I have showed, you can specify the column position in `select` with `dplyr` or `.SDcols` in `data.table`. i.e. `.SDcols= 5:ncol(test)`.

Comment: When I copy and paste the data you posted above into R it runs and then I don't get an error message with the aggregate function, The error message must be due to the way the column was created in excel and then converted to a .csv file. I am still a bit unclear on the  .SDcols= 5:ncol(test) command. I don't understand how that statement tells R to read the columns I mentioned above.

Comment: @HVS Actually, you got the error with `aggregate` by quoting the `"col1"` etc.  We are specifying the position or names of the columns in `.SDcols` and based on that, we loop though those columns (`lapply(.SD, ...`)

Comment: I have 328 columns in total.

Comment: @HVS After aggregating by groups, do you need to take the `sum` rowwise for 5:8, 9:12, etc..

Comment: Yes I would like to take the sum rowwise for those groups.

Comment: @HVS Please check the update.  I created a slightly better example to do the rowwise sum.