# Creating Crosstable with Multiple Variables Summarized by Row Categories

Tags: r, dplyr, crosstable

I am interested in summarizing several outcomes by sample categories and presenting it all in one table. Something with output that resembles:

|  | vs |  | am |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **cyl** | **0** | **1** | **0** | **1** |
| 4 | 1 | 10 | 3 | 8 |
| 6 | 3 | 4 | 4 | 3 |
| 8 | 14 | 0 | 12 | 2 |

were I able to combine ("`cbind`") the tables generated by:

```
ftable(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$vs)
```

and by:

```
ftable(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$am)
```

The [`crosstable()`](https://danchaltiel.github.io/crosstable/) and [`CrossTable()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gmodels/versions/2.18.1/topics/CrossTable) packages showed promise but I couldn't see how to expand it out to multiple groups of columns without nesting them.

As demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66479635/crosstable-with-multiple-items-in-rows-and-columns), `ftable` can get close with:

```
ftable(vs + am ~ cyl, mtcars)
```

except for also nesting `am` within `vs`.

Similarly, `dplyr` gets close via, e.g.,

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>%
  group_by(cyl, vs, am) %>%
  summarize(count = n())
```

or something more complex like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65359191/grouping-by-multiple-variables-and-summarizing-character-frequencies)

but I have *several* variables to present and this nesting defeats the ability to summarize in my case.

Perhaps [`aggregate`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698889/summarizing-multiple-columns-by-two-variables) could work in the hands of a cleverer person than I?

TYIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foo = function(df, grp, vars) {
    lapply(vars, function(nm) {
        tmp = as.data.frame(as.matrix(ftable(reformulate(grp, nm), df)))
        names(tmp) = paste0(nm, "_", names(tmp))
        tmp
    })
}

do.call(cbind, foo(mtcars, "cyl", c("vs", "am", "gear")))
#   vs_0 vs_1 am_0 am_1 gear_3 gear_4 gear_5
# 4    1   10    3    8      1      8      2
# 6    3    4    4    3      2      4      1
# 8   14    0   12    2     12      0      2
```

Answer (score 1):

A solution based on `purrr::map_dfc` and `tidyr::pivot_wider`:

```r
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(c("vs", "am", "gear"), ~ mtcars %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = cyl, 
  names_from = .x, values_from = .x, values_fn = length,
  names_prefix = str_c(.x, "_"), names_sort = T, values_fill = 0) %>%
  {if (.x != "vs")  select(.,-cyl) else .}) %>% arrange(cyl)

#> This message is displayed once per session.
#> # A tibble: 3 × 8
#>     cyl  vs_0  vs_1  am_0  am_1 gear_3 gear_4 gear_5
#>   <dbl> <int> <int> <int> <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
#> 1     4     1    10     3     8      1      8      2
#> 2     6     3     4     4     3      2      4      1
#> 3     8    14     0    12     2     12      0      2
```

Comment: I'm less facile with tidyverse approaches, so this solution is also good to see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This was not really planned, but you can do this using the package crosstable, with the help of a simple `left_join()` call:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(crosstable)

ct1 = crosstable(mtcars, cyl, by=vs)
ct2 = crosstable(mtcars, cyl, by=am)

ct = left_join(ct1, ct2, by=c(".id", "label", "variable"), 
               suffix=c("_vs", "_am"))
ct
#> # A tibble: 3 × 7
#>   .id   label variable `0_vs`       `1_vs`      `0_am`      `1_am`    
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>        <chr>       <chr>       <chr>     
#> 1 cyl   cyl   4        1 (9.09%)    10 (90.91%) 3 (27.27%)  8 (72.73%)
#> 2 cyl   cyl   6        3 (42.86%)   4 (57.14%)  4 (57.14%)  3 (42.86%)
#> 3 cyl   cyl   8        14 (100.00%) 0 (0%)      12 (85.71%) 2 (14.29%)

as_flextable(ct)
```

[image: crosstable]

<sup>Created on 2022-06-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Maybe I will add a `cbind()` method for crosstables [one day](https://github.com/DanChaltiel/crosstable/issues/15), so that the `as_flextable()` output looks better.

Comment: This looks quite promising as a straight-forward and flexible way to address tasks like this.